# How to use putExtra with image view

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass an image view from an activity to another by using intent.putExtra. I read different ways of doing this, like turning it into a bitmap but that option seems to be deprecated. How can I do that?

This is my recycler adapter where I have the setOnClickListener:

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.icu.text.CaseMap
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.newsapp.databinding.NewsItemBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class RecyclerAdapter (
    private var Titles: List<String>,
    private var Images: List<String>,
    private var Authors: List<String>,
    private var Descriptions: List<String>
        ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

            inner class ViewHolder(
                view: View
            ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
                private val binding = NewsItemBinding.bind(view)

                val itemTitle: TextView = binding.tvTitle
                val itemImage: ImageView = binding.ivNewsImage

                fun bind(urlToImage:String){
                    Picasso.get().load(urlToImage).into(binding.ivNewsImage)
                }


                init {
                    itemImage.setOnClickListener{
                        val intent = Intent(view.context, PostActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("title",itemTitle.text)
                        intent.putExtra("image",itemImage)
                        view.context.startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemTitle.text = Titles[position]
        val itemImage = Images[position]
        holder.bind(itemImage)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Titles.size
    }
}
```

This is my PostActivity, which is the second activity and the one that should show the imageview from the first activity:

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.media.Image
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.newsapp.databinding.ActivityPostBinding

class PostActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPostBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)
        binding = ActivityPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //get title
        var detailTitle = intent.getStringExtra("title")
        binding.tvTitleItem.text = detailTitle

        //get image, not completed yet
        var detailImage = intent.getStringExtra("image")
        binding.ivNewsImageDetail = detailImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to pass an image view from an activity to another by using intent.putExtra

Sorry, but that is not an option.

> This is my PostActivity, which is the second activity and the one that should show the imageview from the first activity

It should show the *image* that is shown in the first activity.

Your first activity is getting that image from a URL. So, you could pass the URL in an extra to the second activity, and have the second activity get that image from that URL. Since you are using an image-loading library (Picasso), you can work to ensure that the library caches the actual bytes of the image itself, so that you only download the image content once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the image url not the image view

please replace

```
intent.putExtra("image",itemImage)
```

with

```
                intent.putExtra("image",itemTitle.image)
```